# Overriding inherited behavior

Tags: python, django-models

I am using Multi-table inheritance for an object, and I need to limit the choices of the parent object foreign key references to only the rules that apply the child system.

```
from schedule.models import Event, Rule

class AirShowRule(Rule):
    """
    Inheritance of the schedule.Rule
    """
    rule_type = models.TextField(default='onAir')

class AirShow(Event):
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/airshow', null=True, blank= True)
    thumb_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/airshow', null=True, blank= True)
```

Now, in the admin, I only want the AirShowRule(s) to be the choices for an AirShow(Event). What I get is all the rules that are in the schedule.event system.

I am inheriting from django-schedule found at http://code.google.com/p/django-schedule/

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the structure of the classes listed, and you should add this:

```
class AirShow(Event):
   ... your stuff...
   rule = models.ForeignKey(AirShowRule, null = True, blank = True,
                            verbose_name="VERBOSE NAME", help_text="HELP TEXT")
```

that should get everything straight (**changed to "AirShowRule" from "Rule"**)

*you should also make sure that you implement **AirShowRule** more completely as I imagine you aren't overriding rule_type, and if you are, I don't think it'll do all that you want*

*see: [models.py:23](http://code.google.com/p/django-schedule/source/browse/trunk/schedule/models.py#23)

...this line was taken from [models.py:103](http://code.google.com/p/django-schedule/source/browse/trunk/schedule/models.py#103) with the modification of the arguments: verbose___name & help_text (probably optional, but I'll leave that for you to inspect)

**Be aware that I haven't used these modules before, but this should give you a push to keep going :)**

Comment: Thanks I am looking into this solution.

Comment: I was put on another issue, will get back to this one next week.